# Is there a proper way to fill an electrical panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel, installation

I'm installing a subpanel and will submite a panel schedule with my permit application.  I have never installed a panel before, so I wonder if there is a proper way to install the breakers.  Should larger breakers (more amps/double pole) go farthest away from the main breaker (does it matter)?  Also, should I fill in one side of the panel first, or try to fill it from top down keeping each side balanced?

My understanding is that either way the load should be evenly distributed across the two legs (panel will have 240V).

Comment: Depends on the specifics of the panel (WRT balancing, buss stab loading, etc.), but there's not really a general rule, as panels differ in details.

Comment: Generally, (and I use that term loosely) it's best to have the higher amperage breakers as close to the main breaker as reasonably possible. It's not a big deal, just best practice.   Nearly all panels are equally supplied on the busses, but I got snipped by another person here that had a panel in which the main busses weren't evenly supplied.   We could give you better advice if you include the  brand and model of the sub-panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing is to watch your stab limits.   Breakers clip on to panel parts called "bus stabs".  They have a practical current limit, often stated on the panel label.

Some people get it in their head "put the biggest breakers up top" (as if to reduce the few inches current must flow down the bus, as if that matters).  Then they fit a 100A breaker opposite a 50A breaker, and *voilà*, they have put 150A on the bus stabs in the first two rows.

Also beware of "double-stuffing" panels - lots of people get the 'bright' idea to save themselves the cost of a pizza by getting the smallest panel they can.  Then they either choose from the outset, or are forced into later, going with "double-stuff" breakers that put 2 breakers effectively in 1 space (or 2 240V breakers in 2 spaces).  I recently saw a setup that had a 40/40 quadplex across from a 30 2-pole.   The person wanted to double-stuff the 30 to a 30/50 to feed a subpanel.  *Notice a problem?* You now have an 80A (40/40) breaker across from an 80A (30/50) breaker.  Stab limits again!

Go big. Go really big. Spaces are cheap.  Regrets are expensive.